# getting values from a select and moving them to a ul - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, dom-manipulation

I am creating a plugin at the moment, that allows me to change select boxes into something pretty, I do this by changing the select boxes that are found on a page in to definition lists, with the definition description I am nesting a ul in it, and the li are the values from the select list.

I am having a problem however, if for example I have 3 select boxes on the page I get a strange mistake, and I cannot pinpoint where in my code I am going wrong but what is that multiple `dd` are being added to each `dl` so for example the second `dl` has 2 `dd` where as it should have one, like the 3rd select box should have 1 `dd` but it has 3, it seems like the amount of `dd`'s created matches the index of the loop. How can I make so that only one dd, is created per dl, and that correct options are added.

This is my plugin code,

```
    /***********
* Select-Me create pretty select lists using a <ul> inplace of the <select>
* Author: Simon Ainley (on behalf of The Factory Agency)
* Version: 0.0.1
***********/
(function($){  
    $.fn.selectMe = function(options) {  
        var defaults = {
            select_text : null,
            remove_first_value : false,
            speed : 1000
        }

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function(index) {
            //get an instance of the object we are working with
            var obj = $(this);
            var obj_name = obj.attr('name');
            console.log(obj_name);
            obj.closest('form').append('<input type="hidden" class="dropdown_value" value="" name="'+obj_name+'"/>');
            var options = $("option", obj);
            var replacement_list_heading = "<dl class='dropdown "+obj_name+"'><dt><span>"+defaults.select_text+"</span><a href=''>Go</a></dt></dl>";
            obj.closest('form').prepend(replacement_list_heading);
            var values_start = "<dd class='shadow_50'><ul></ul></dd>";
            $(".dropdown").append(values_start);
            if(defaults.remove_first_value == true) {
                options.splice(0, 1);
            }
            options.each(function(index){
                    $(".dropdown." + obj_name + " dd ul").append(
                        '<li><a href="#"><span class="option">' + 
                        $(this).text() + '</span><span class="value">' + 
                        $(this).val() + '</span></a></li>'
                    );

            });

            obj.remove();

            $('.dropdown li a').hover(function() {
                $(this).parent('li').addClass('hover');
            }, function() { 
                $(this).parent('li').removeClass('hover');
            });

            $(".dropdown dt a").click(function(e) {
                $(this).closest("dl").find("dd").slideToggle(defaults.speed);
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            $(".dropdown ul a").click(function(e) {
                var value = $(this).find('span').text();
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                $(".dropdown_value").val(value);
                $(".dropdown dt span").text($('.selected .option').text());
                $(".dropdown dd").slideUp(defaults.speed);
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    };  
})(jQuery);
```

I believe the problems are within these sections of the code,

`var options = $("option", obj);` - I think I need to differentiate between each set of options?

```
options.each(function(index){

                    $(".dropdown." + obj_name + " dd ul").append(
                        '<li><a href="#"><span class="option">' + 
                        $(this).text() + '</span><span class="value">' + 
                        $(this).val() + '</span></a></li>'
                    );

            });
```

I believe this bit is just looping regardless of whether it should stop and add the options to a new `dd`?

any help would be great!

How I invoke my plugin,

```
    $(".type select").selectMe({
    select_text : "I'm looking for...",
    remove_first_value : true,
});

$(".skill select").selectMe({
    select_text : "Skill",
    remove_first_value : true,
});

$(".gender select").selectMe({
    select_text : "Gender",
    remove_first_value : true,
});
```

and the HTML that is changed,

```
    div class="grid_4">
                        <fieldset>
                                <div class="formRow drop_down">

<select name="type">
<option value="0" selected="selected">I'm looking for...</option>
<option value="1">actors</option>
<option value="2">presenters</option>
<option value="3">voice overs</option>
</select>
    </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div class="grid_4">

                        <fieldset>
                                <div class="formRow drop_down">
<select name="skill">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Skill</option>
<option value="1">actors</option>
<option value="2">presenters</option>
<option value="3">voice overs</option>
<option value="4">dancers</option>
<option value="5">accents</option>

<option value="6">film</option>
<option value="7">tv</option>
</select>
    </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div class="grid_4">
                        <fieldset>  
                                <div class="formRow drop_down">
<select name="gender">

<option value="0" selected="selected">Gender</option>
<option value="1">male</option>
<option value="2">female</option>
</select>
    </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Could you include how you invoke your plugin with some example HTML? And why the empty if()?

Answer (score 0):

As it stands I'm not sure how it is executing at all, the selector ".type select" won't return anything from the HTML you've supplied - for that to work you'd need a `<div class='type'`> and `</div>` wrapped around your first `<select>`.

I can see why you are getting multiple DDs though, in your plugin you execute this:

```
var values_start = "<dd class='shadow_50'><ul></ul></dd>";
$(".dropdown").append(values_start);
```

That selector will target every .dropdown class you have created so far on the page. So for each subsequent call to the plugin, you'll be adding DD elements into the DL elements you have already created.

I think you want `$(".dropdown." + obj_name).append(values_start);` instead.

Because your event calls at the end are targetting the .dropdown class in general, they'll suffer from the same problem, creating multiple events on each of the elements.

You're making quite a few selector calls throughout your plugin which will cause jQuery to look through the entire DOM (e.g. in your options .each function). Since at quite a few of the steps you're just building up one single element which you can then add into the page, you should probably think about just building this up and adding it into the page without using further selectors.